# Updating the InsertUI elements

Tags: r, shiny

Suppose I have a Data frame as given below and I created multiple panels using the insert UI elements. How do I, in my case update the values in these multiple panels.

I could update the inputs for the first panel but things get messier as I try to update the other added panels. Suppose in one panel I need data for Earthquake in 1985 and in the other panel I need data for Earthquake in 1990.

How do I do that? For the first panel it works fine and I could toggle between 1985 and 1990 data, but as I add new panel the updates doesn't work accordingly in any of the panels including the first one.

Also the the position of delete button not changing left or right with CSS commands, WHY?

Any help from anyone is appreciated as R is a bit getting difficult for me.

Here is the code I tried working on but without success

```
 # Demo dataframe

 DT <- data.frame(Year = c(1980,1985,1985,1990,1990,1995), Events = 
 c("Storm","Earthquake","Flood","Draught","Earthquake","Flood"), Area_Loss 
 = c(100, 200, 400, 500, 450,300), Money = 
 c(1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000))

 #UI Logic 

 ui <- fluidPage( h4("Updating InserUIs",
        inlineCSS("#delete_div{margin-top:1em;}"),
        selectInput("events","Events",choices = as.character(DT$Events)),
        tags$div(id = "Panels"),
        actionButton("add","Add")    
           ))


  #Server Logic 

  server <- function(session, input, output){

   vals <- reactiveValues(btn = 0)

     #Adding and Removing buttons 

   observeEvent(input$add,ignoreNULL = FALSE,{

        vals$btn <- vals$btn +1

   insertUI(

   selector = "#Panels",
   ui = splitLayout(id = paste0("Selection",vals$btn), where = "afterEnd",
                   cellWidths = rep("33.33%",3),

   selectInput(paste("year",vals$btn +1,sep = ""), "Year", choices = 
        as.numeric(DT$Year), selected = ""),
   numericInput(paste("area",vals$btn +1,sep = ""), "Area", min = 0, max = 
        10000, value ="", step = 1),
   numericInput(paste("money",vals$btn +1,sep = ""), "Money", min = 0, max 
        = 10000, value = "", step =1),
   div(id = "delete_div",actionButton(paste0("delete",vals$btn), 
         "Delete"))))

     observeEvent(input[[paste0("delete",vals$btn)]],{
        shiny::removeUI(selector = paste0("#Selection",vals$btn))
         vals$btn <- vals$btn - 1

   })
 })

     #For Updating the inserted UIs

      Year_Value <- reactive({
            Year <- c(input[["year"]])
              if(vals$btn>0){
                 for(i in 1:vals$btn){
               Year <- c(Year,input[[paste0("year", i+1)]])
                  }
             Year <- paste(Year,collapse = "\n")     
         }
      })

       #Updates based on Year and Events

   observeEvent(input$events,
    updateSelectInput(session,paste("year",vals$btn +1,sep = 
    ""),"Year", choices = as.numeric(DT$Year)[DT$Events == input$events], 
    selected = ""))

   observeEvent(Year_Value(),
    updateNumericInput(session,paste("area",vals$btn +1,sep = 
    ""),"Area",min= 0, max= 50000,value = DT$Area_Loss[DT$Year == 
    Year_Value() & DT$Events== input$events] ,step = 0.1))

   observeEvent(Year_Value(),
    updateNumericInput(session,paste("money",vals$btn +1,sep = 
    ""),"Money",min= 0, max= 50000,value = DT$Money[DT$Year == 
    Year_Value() & DT$Events == input$events],step = 0.1))

  }

   shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I want my updates to work properly for all the inserted ui elements. I will be extremely grateful to anyone contributing towards solving my problem. I am looking for any kind of help in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying to better understand your question. Are you adding panels in order to update values in the preexisting table? Or to append new rows to the table? Or is the goal of adding/removing panels to be able to browse different events by year in each panel?

Comment: Some other quick notes. The delete button is missing because there's no space for it. In `splitPanel` try `cellWidths = rep("25", 4)` and the button should appear. Also, the `Year_Value` reactive is missing a `return(Year)`, you are updating it, but not returning it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The table was provided only to provide an illustration that what the input panels are doing. In reality I don't want the table and you second guess of adding/remove panels is the way I want it it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not answering your task using `insertUI`, but it is more of a proposal for an alternative, easier implementation. You can use the package `DT` which allows editing tables in place in a shiny app. Take look at the documentation here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/ and an demo shiny app here: https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/. A quick example using your data:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
# Demo dataframe

DT <- data.frame(
  Year = c(1980, 1985, 1985, 1990, 1990, 1995),
  Events =
    c(
      "Storm",
      "Earthquake",
      "Flood",
      "Draught",
      "Earthquake",
      "Flood"
    ),
  Area_Loss
  = c(100, 200, 400, 500, 450, 300),
  Money =
    c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000)
)

ui <- basicPage(
  DTOutput("ee"),
  tags$hr(),
  h3("table after editing:"),
  tableOutput("edited")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ee <- renderDT({
    datatable(data = DT, editable = "row", filter = "top")
  })

  # edit a row
  observeEvent(input$ee_cell_edit, {
    DT <<- editData(data = DT, info = input$ee_cell_edit, 'ee')
    output$edited <- renderTable(DT)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative anyway. I will see if it could be implemented in my app.